# Email confirmation after User Changed email on Allauth

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I would like to know if there is an automated way to trigger the functionality of email confirmation on [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) on email update.

When an (already confirmed) user updates their email, I would like an email to be sent to the user to confirm that they own the address. 
I found that a signal exists,

```
allauth.account.signals.email_changed(request, user, from_email_address, to_email_address)
```

> Sent when a primary email address has been changed.

I am not sure if the mechanism is already bundled or if i need to implement in a similar manner like the answer i found in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25292052/send-email-confirmation-after-registration-django).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is out-of-the-box functionality. There is no need to hook up to signals and implement this yourself. Simply point your users to /accounts/email/. When they add an email address the verification email is sent

Comment: Ooooooo many many thanks!!!! I was looking for it, but i could not find it.... thank you soooo much! You saved me!