# How to activate an account with e-mail that has been registred Django

Tags: python, django, email, django-views, django-templates

I want to when my user is registred to generate a token and that token to be sent to e-mail to when I click the link verify the account, but im getting an error and don't know what to do

my settings:

```
if DEBUG:
    EMAIL_HOST = 'stmp.gmail.com'
    #EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.stmp.EmailBackend'
    EMAIL_PORT = 587
    EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
    EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'dffhjamsdfelafgfumn@gmail.com'
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'definetely this is my password# important

else:
    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

Views:

```
def account_register(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('account:dashboard')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        registerForm = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if registerForm.is_valid():
            user = registerForm.save(commit=False)
            user.email = registerForm.cleaned_data['email']
            user.set_password(registerForm.cleaned_data['password'])
            user.is_active = False
            email_to = user.email
            user.save()
            email_subject = 'Ative sua conta'
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            message = render_to_string('account/registration/account_activation_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })

            email_body = message

            email = EmailMessage(
                email_subject,
                email_body,
                settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [email_to])
            email.send()
            return HttpResponse('registered succesfully and activation sent')
    else:
        registerForm = RegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'account/registration/register.html', {'form': registerForm})


def account_activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64)
        user = UserBase.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, user.DoesNotExist):
        user = None
    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('account:dashboard')
    else:
        return render(request, 'account/registration/activation_invalid.html')
```

console error:

this is a lorem ipsum because I need to add more info to post the question

dfkwssdsd

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kayna\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\ebrelease\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\kayna\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\ebrelease\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kayna\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\ebrelease\account\views.py", line 134, in account_register
    email.send()
  File "C:\Users\kayna\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\ebrelease\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py", line 298, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "C:\Users\kayna\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\ebrelease\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 124, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "C:\Users\kayna\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\ebrelease\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 80, in open
    self.connection = self.connection_class(
  File "C:\Users\kayna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\smtplib.py", line 255, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "C:\Users\kayna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\smtplib.py", line 341, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\kayna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\smtplib.py", line 312, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
  File "C:\Users\kayna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\socket.py", line 824, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Users\kayna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\socket.py", line 955, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
[25/May/2022 02:54:16] "POST /django-store-account/register/ HTTP/1.1" 500 103484
[25/May/2022 02:55:41] "POST /django-store-account/register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6700
Internal Server Error: /django-store-account/register/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kayna\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\ebrelease\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\kayna\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\ebrelease\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kayna\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\ebrelease\account\views.py", line 134, in account_register
    email.send()
  File "C:\Users\kayna\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\ebrelease\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py", line 298, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "C:\Users\kayna\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\ebrelease\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 124, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "C:\Users\kayna\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\ebrelease\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 80, in open
    self.connection = self.connection_class(
  File "C:\Users\kayna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\smtplib.py", line 255, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "C:\Users\kayna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\smtplib.py", line 341, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\kayna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\smtplib.py", line 312, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
  File "C:\Users\kayna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\socket.py", line 824, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Users\kayna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\socket.py", line 955, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
[25/May/2022 02:56:01] "POST /django-store-account/register/ HTTP/1.1" 500 103526
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Email verification in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55578387/email-verification-in-django)

Comment: not quite because I dont know much, I dont quite know to use all that code and for what I noticed he did not send the link to activate the account in the body of the email, he sent it to an other page I  dont understand it

Comment: I created that token file but how do I generate the token in my  def register account, send it along  with the e-mail and build the method to activate it

Comment: updated it, please check